# Forcing MongoDB to prefetch memory

Tags: linux, mongodb, memory-management, centos, memory-mapped-files

I'm currently running MongoDB 2.6.7 on CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core).
Soon after the server starts, as well as (sometimes) after a period of inactivity (at least a few minutes) all queries take longer than usual. After a while, their speeds increase and stabilize around a much shorter duration (for a particular (more complex) query, the difference is from 30 seconds initially, to about 7 after the "warm-up" period).

After monitoring my VM using both `top` and various network traffic monitoring tools, I've noticed that the bottleneck is hit because of hard page faults (which had been my hunch from the beginning).

Given that my data takes up <2Gb and that my machine has 3.5 GB available, my collections should all fit in-memory (even with their indexes). And they actually do end up being fetched, but only on an on-demand basis, which can end up having a relatively negative impact on the user experience.

[MongoDB uses memory-mapped files to operate on collections](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/). Is there any way to force the operating system to prefetch the whole file into memory as soon as MongoDB starts up, instead of waiting for queries to trigger random page faults?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From mongodb docs:

The [touch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/touch/) command loads data from the data storage layer into memory. touch can load the data (i.e. documents) indexes or both documents and indexes. Use this command to ensure that a collection, and/or its indexes, are in memory before another operation. By loading the collection or indexes into memory, mongod will ideally be able to perform subsequent operations more efficiently.

Comment: `touch` was removed in [MongoDB Version 4.2](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/4.2-compatibility/#mmapv1-specific-command)